# run etcd with ansible

Tags: deployment, ansible, etcd

When run

```
etcd -peer-addr 127.0.0.1:7001 -addr 127.0.0.1:4001 -data-dir machines/machine1 -name machine1 &
```

I must to press enter in order to get back the console and etcd run in background

**ANSIBLE**

How can I recreate this purpose with ansible?

I want start etcd with ansible in this way

```
- name: run etcd like leader
  shell: "etcd -peer-addr 127.0.0.1:7001 -addr 127.0.0.1:4001 -data-dir machines/machine1 -name machine2 &"
```

ansible keep holding the return of command and no continue for next task.

---

maybe a solution is running etcd in background. I don't know how

---

**using**

- ansible 1.6.6
- etcd 0.4.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs on [async mode](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_async.html). You can set `async` to some really long value, say 10 years in seconds (315569260), and set `poll` to 0.

This is a bit of a hack though. The better approach would be a systemd or init script that runs the process as a properly as a daemon.

Comment: I try with async way; but then the etcd process is killed, not stay running in background.

Comment: indeed, as Ben said, it's a hack. The etcd folks recommend using `daemon` or `upstart`. `supervisord` is also an option.

Comment: I am triying with supervisor, but the same command run from console and not run from supervisor. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26025491/using-supervisor-to-run-etcd-cluster